# JSON.parse parsing JSON with nested objects

Tags: javascript, json

I'm attempting to parse a JSON string with nested objects received in the response of a post request. After running `JSON.parse(responseText)`, the result is in the following format:

```
[{
  "atco":"43000156407",
  "location":{
    "longitude":"-1.7876500000000000",
    "latitude":"52.4147200000000000","
    timestamp":"2013-03-19 11:30:00"
   },
  "name":"Solihull Station Interchange",
  "road":"STATION APPROACH",
  "direction":"NA",
  "locality":"Solihull",
  "town":"Solihull"}, ...
```

I thought I would then be able pull values out using the following as an example, but all I get is undefined.

```
var atco = json[0].atco;
```

I've also tried `json[0][0]` but that returns an individual character from the JSON (`[`) . Does this indicate the JSON hasn't parsed correctly, or is this expected behaviour and I'm just referencing incorrectly?

Comment: You'll have to quote how you're parsing that. If the JSON really is as shown, `json[0].atco` is the correct way to access the `atco` property of the first entry in the array. So that leaves us speculating about what's going wrong, which isn't useful to anyone. :-)

Comment: please write compelete json script.

Comment: if json refers to that object as you've written it, it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/XmchJ/  Something else going on, I suspect "am not i am" has it figured out

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This means that your JSON is being double encoded. Make sure you only encode it once on the server.

As proof, after you've parsed it, parse it again.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(resposneText);

var parsed2 = JSON.parse(parsed);

alert(parsed2.atco);
```

---

Either that, or you're parsing it but then trying to select the data from the original string. This would obviously not work.