# javax.json produces uncomprehensible json

Tags: java, json, node.js, jersey

I have a Java class with two atrributes that I convert to json using this method. I followed this other answer: 
[Return JSONArray instead of JSONObject, Jersey JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849526/return-jsonarray-instead-of-jsonobject-jersey-jax-rs)

```
public String toString(){
    // takes advantage of toString() implementation to format {"a":"b"}
    JsonObject json =  Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("sentence", sentence)
            .add( "category", category).build();
    return json.toString();
}
```

The String I get is encapsulated into an ArrayList of strings, and sent via HTTP (I am using Jersey):

```
return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
```

How ever, the node client is use cannot parse it properly: it gets the array part, accesses the elements perfectly. But not the json keys and values; 
returns undefined:

```
jsonRespuesta = JSON.parse(body)[0];
console.log(jsonRespuesta);
console.log("Frase: " +jsonRespuesta.sentence + " ,Categoria: " + jsonRespuesta.category);
```

Returns:

```
{"sentence":"hola","category":"2"}
Frase: undefined ,Categoria: undefined
```

What's failing? If it helps, capturing the packets with wireshark displays the array members as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your java client encoding the JSON twice? I noticed you are adding json strings to an ArrayList, but you should really be adding objects to the ArrayList and then stringifying the whole thing once.

Try using `JSON.parse()` again on `jsonRepuesta` and see if that gets you what you're looking for. Alternatively, log out a `typeof jsonRepuesta` -- looks like it's still a string.

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004603/json-parse-parsing-json-with-nested-objects).

Comment: The key was that: making and ArrayList<JsonObject> and aplying the toString to the whole array. The json was encoded twice, indeed.